# Is it possible to store the contents of a text file into a string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I don't mean .load() since I don't want to display the file's contents. Instead I want to store the contents in a string so I can perform string manipulation on it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try getting the data using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
var myData;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your url",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        myData = data;
    }
});
```

If the data is in JSON format you can look at [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)